# How to show/hide taskbar from a desktop shortcut

Tags: windows, taskbar, shortcut-file

How to show/hide taskbar from a desktop shortcut without opening settings menu

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A command or message or DLL call to set automatic hiding of Windows taskbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53367237/a-command-or-message-or-dll-call-to-set-automatic-hiding-of-windows-taskbar)

Comment: I thing so. but how can i implement this without using a third party application. can i create using vbs or other code.

Comment: The linked question shows how to do it in AutoHotKey. The underlying algorithm should be apparent, and you can translate it to whatever other language you like, assuming it can call Win32 APIs.

Comment: this shortcut location opens task view:- explorer shell:::{3080F90E-D7AD-11D9-BD98-0000947B0257} .Is there way to do so?

Comment: There is no `shell::` value for changing taskbar show/hide. It's not clear why people expect every single feature to have a "can be triggered from a batch file".

Answer (score 3):

You need to enable autohide mode in settings. Then use `Win + T`.

Comment: I think (or presume) that the OP wants to do this programmatically.

Comment: @AdrianMole Thought he meant a keyboard shortcut from the desktop.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you will have to do it manually . Right click on task bar then go to taskbar settings then turn on Automatically hide the taskbar in desktop mode then simply you can press ctrl+Esc to see taskbar from any window.

Comment: I thing so. but how can i implement this without using a third party application. can i create using vbs or other code.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it by using AHK . AutoHotKey.
If you hide it,  there is going to be a transparent taskbar. so the best thing is setting it to AUTOHIDE.1) install ahk
2) go to desktop  , right click , create ahk script
3) open with notepad, delete everything , paste next
4)open script  use ALT+BACKSPACE    & CTRL+BACKSPACE

```
 ;Show taskbar 
; ctrl + Backspace   Set AUTO HIDE TASKBAR OFF
        ^Backspace::       
                HideShowTaskbar2(False)
                HideShowTaskbar2(action)
                {
                    static ABM_SETSTATE := 0xA, ABS_AUTOHIDE := 0x1, ABS_ALWAYSONTOP := 0x2
                    VarSetCapacity(APPBARDATA, size := 2*A_PtrSize + 2*4 + 16 + A_PtrSize, 0)
                    NumPut(size, APPBARDATA), NumPut(WinExist("ahk_class Shell_TrayWnd"), APPBARDATA, A_PtrSize)
                    NumPut(action ? ABS_AUTOHIDE : ABS_ALWAYSONTOP, APPBARDATA, size - A_PtrSize)
                    DllCall("Shell32\SHAppBarMessage", UInt, ABM_SETSTATE, Ptr, &APPBARDATA)    
                }   
        Return

 ;Hide taskbar 
          ; Alt + Backspace    Set AUTO HIDE TASKBAR ON
        !Backspace::    
                HideShowTaskbar(True)   
                HideShowTaskbar(action)
                {   
                    static ABM_SETSTATE := 0xA, ABS_AUTOHIDE := 0x1, ABS_ALWAYSONTOP := 0x2
                    VarSetCapacity(APPBARDATA, size := 2*A_PtrSize + 2*4 + 16 + A_PtrSize, 0)
                    NumPut(size, APPBARDATA), NumPut(WinExist("ahk_class Shell_TrayWnd"), APPBARDATA, A_PtrSize)
                    NumPut(action ? ABS_AUTOHIDE : ABS_ALWAYSONTOP, APPBARDATA, size - A_PtrSize)
                    DllCall("Shell32\SHAppBarMessage", UInt, ABM_SETSTATE, Ptr, &APPBARDATA)            
                }   
        return
```

Comment: I tried the above AutoHotkey script in Windows 11 and it did not work.  Ctrl+Backspace did nothing and Alt+Backspace shrank the size of the Taskbar but did not hide it.  Open full screen windows did not automatically resize as happens when the Taskbar is actually hidden.

Answer (score -1):

You need to enable autohide mode in settings.

```
ToggleTaskbar()
{
    Static A_WinID := ""

    If Not WinActive("ahk_class Shell_TrayWnd")
    {
        A_WinID := WinExist("A")
        WinShow, ahk_class Shell_TrayWnd
        WinActivate, ahk_class Shell_TrayWnd
    }
    Else
    {
        If A_WinID
        {
            WinActivate, ahk_id %A_WinID%
            A_WinID := ""
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried the above in AutoHotkey and all it did was activate and deactivate the current windows.